# Change alpha value of the Standard Shader

Tags: unity, shaders

I want to edit the Standard shader provided by Unity in order to change the alpha value of a fragment (pixel) according to given parameters I pass to the shader.

For now, [thanks to this link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1107427/how-to-customize-standard-shader-repeating-texture.html), I have been able to :

1. Retrieve the standard shader,
2. Retrieve a custom `Core.cginc` I included in the `DEFERRED` pass of the custom shader,
3. Create a custom Editor script to handle the Shader and my custom parameters,
4. Selecte `Fade` as the rendering mode of the shader to handle transparency, using the custom editor script,
5. Create a custom file replacing `UnityStandardInput.cginc` and changed the references in the `Core.cginc` file.

But now, I can't seem to figure **where** to change the alpha value of the fragment. I've tried a ton of possibilities in the `Core.cginc` file. Changing the **color** and the **map** of the Albedo works, but I can't find where the final alpha value is set.

I've browsed the files in the `CGIncludes` folder in the [builtin shaders of Unity](https://unity3d.com/fr/get-unity/download/archive).

- `UnityStandardCore.cginc` : Already tried many possibilities (including the returned value of `Alpha` declared in `UnityStandardInput.cginc`
- `CustomInput.cginc` : `Alpha` function, no effect

Since the files are huge, I don't feel it will be useful to copy-paste them here.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to solve it myself. In the end, you will need at least 6 files :

- Shader file itself
- Core.cginc
- CoreForward.cginc
- CoreForwardSimple.cginc
- Input.cginc
- Meta.cginc

In all these files, replace all the references to the `UnityStandardXXX` by your custom files. Don't miss any !

Then, in the Core.cginc file, I've edited the `FragmentSetup` function to change the value of the `alpha` variable : `half alpha = Alpha(i_tex.xy) ;`

Comment: 4.x shaders were so much easier to play with

Comment: That's the price to pay for PBR I guess ! But it's a pain, for sure.

Comment: Must be. And now I use Shader Forge for all my shader needs (totally worth the money).